# duplicate post entries when comment updated via jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Okay so I thought I had solved this problem. But the solution still evades me!

I have a ajax powered social chat application allowing comments and likes etc built with php, mysql and jquery. But when I post a comment the ajax returns a duplicate post with comment updated, so when you comment again you end up with mutiple duplicate posts. The Msql entries are fine (ie no duplication). All my other functions and updates work fine, so this is a severe pain in the bum!

Apologies for the amount of code but I am just trying to give you all the information - all thoughts and answers much appreciated!

Here is the start page HTML:

```
 <html>

 <div class="usermsg">

   <?php


    $sql = "SELECT post.post, post.posttime, post.pid_imageurl, post.likes, user.name, comments.comment, user.uid_imageurl, comments.comment_uid, post.pid
                FROM post
                INNER JOIN user
                ON post.uid=user.uid
                LEFT JOIN comments
                ON comments.comment_pid=post.pid
                ORDER BY pid DESC";



    $result = mysql_query($sql);


    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){?>



    <?php
    $pid = $row['pid'];
    $formattime = date("g:i:a",$row['posttime']);
    //echo $row['pid']; for testing
    echo '<p class="speechbubble">'.$row['post'].'<br><br><img class= "userprofileimage" src="'.$row['uid_imageurl'].'" alt="user profile image"/> Posted by '.$row['name'].' at '.$formattime. '</p>';


     ?>

         <p class="likepara">this post has <? echo $row['likes']; ?> likes  <a class="like" pid=<? echo $row['pid']; ?> href="#">like</a></p>    

           <div class="editable" pid="<? echo $row['pid'];?>" contentEditable="true">add comment...</div>

   <?php

    $sql_comments = "SELECT comments.comment, comments.comment_time, user.name, user.uid_imageurl FROM comments
                    INNER JOIN user
                    ON  comments.comment_uid = user.uid
                    WHERE comment_pid = '$pid' ORDER BY cid DESC";


    $result_comments = mysql_query($sql_comments);                
    $numrows_comments=mysql_num_rows($result_comments);//num of rows


    if($numrows_comments==0) //no comments
      {
           echo '<p class="commentsheader">Comments</p><br>';
           echo 'This post has no comments yet, be the first!';
           echo '<br><br><br><hr><br><br>';

      }else{
           echo '<p class="commentsheader">Comments</p><br>';
     while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result_comments)){

       $formattime_comment = date("g:i:a",$row['comment_time']);
       echo '<p class="comment">'.$row['comment'].'<br><img class="commentprofileimage" src="'.$row['uid_imageurl'].'" alt="user profile image"/>Posted by '.$row['name']. ' at ' .$formattime_comment. '</p>';
       //echo '<img class="commentprofileimage" src="'.$row['uid_imageurl'].'" alt="user profile image"/>'

     }//$sql_comments

     echo '<hr><br><br>';


      }//else end



    }//$sql


    ?>




   </div><!--user msg--


   </html>
```

The jquery function:

```
   $(".editable").live('click', function(){

        $(this).empty();

        $(this).mouseout(function() {

            var comment = $(this).html();
            var postid = $(this).attr("pid");
            var commentuserid = $("#loggedin").attr("uid");

            if(comment == ""){
                return false;
            }else{
                    var datastring = 'comment=' + comment + '&postid=' + postid + '&commentuserid=' + commentuserid;


                    //save with ajax clear box and then load back in
                    $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "uploadcomment.php",
                    data: datastring,
                    success: function(data){


                    $(".usermsg").html(data);

                                }
                    });
            }
        });
  });
```

the update php (basically the same as the inital html page being updated).

```
    <?php

    include("connectdb.php");
    include_once("secure.php");



    //still repeating posts when mutiple comments added?
    $commentpostid = $_POST['postid'];
    $commentuserid = $_POST['commentuserid'];
    $comment = protect($_POST['comment']);
$time =time();

$comment = strip_tags($comment);
    $time =time();

$sql_insert_comments = "INSERT INTO comments
              (comment_uid, comment_pid, comment, comment_time)
              VALUES
              ($commentuserid,$commentpostid, '$comment', $time)";

$insert_comments_result = mysql_query($sql_insert_comments);

    ?>

     <?

    $sql = "SELECT post.post, post.posttime, post.pid_imageurl, post.likes, user.name, comments.comment, user.uid_imageurl, comments.comment_uid, post.pid
                FROM post
                INNER JOIN user
                ON post.uid=user.uid
                LEFT JOIN comments
                ON comments.comment_pid=post.pid
                ORDER BY pid DESC";

    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){?>

    <?
    $pid = $row['pid'];
    $formattime = date("g:i:a",$row['posttime']);
echo '<p class="speechbubble">'.$row['post'].'<br><br><img class= "userprofileimage" src="'.$row['uid_imageurl'].'" alt="user profile image"/> Posted by '.$row['name'].' at '.$formattime. '</p>';

    //echo '<p class="speechbubble">'.$row['post'].'</p>';
    //echo '<p class="msgholder" >Posted by '.$row['name'].' at '.$formattime. '<img class= "userprofileimage" src="'.$row['uid_imageurl'].'" alt="user profile image"/></p>';
?>

    <p class="likepara">this post has <? echo $row['likes']; ?> likes  <a class="like" pid=<? echo $row['pid']; ?> href="#">like</a></p>    

    <div class="editable" pid="<? echo $row['pid'];?>" contentEditable="true">
             add comment...
    </div>

    <?

    $sql_comments = "SELECT comments.comment, comments.comment_time, user.name, user.uid_imageurl FROM comments
                    INNER JOIN user
                    ON  comments.comment_uid = user.uid
                    WHERE comment_pid = '$pid' ORDER BY cid DESC";


    $result_comments = mysql_query($sql_comments);                

      $numrows_comments=mysql_num_rows($result_comments);//num of rows


              if($numrows_comments==0) //no comments
            {
                 echo '<p class="commentsheader">Comments</p><br>';
                 echo 'This post has no comments yet, be the first!';
                 echo '<br><br><br><hr><br><br>';

            }else{
                  echo '<p class="commentsheader">Comments</p><br>';
                  while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result_comments)){
                  $formattime_comment = date("g:i:a",$row['comment_time']);
                   //echo '<p class="comment">'.$row['comment'].'</p>';
                   //echo '<p class="commentposter">posted by '.$row['name']. ' at ' .$formattime_comment. '<img class="commentprofileimage" src="'.$row['uid_imageurl'].'" alt="user profile image"/></p>';
                    echo '<p class="comment">'.$row['comment'].'<br><img class="commentprofileimage" src="'.$row['uid_imageurl'].'" alt="user profile image"/>Posted by '.$row['name']. ' at ' .$formattime_comment. '</p>';

            }//$sql_comments

            echo '<hr><br><br>';

      }//else end

    }//$sql


    ?>




    </div>









</div>
```

Comment: I don't see any mysql UPDATE function, just insert. How are you supposed to update the comment without actually using the update function in the database?

Comment: no comments can be edited (updated) at present, just added as new comments and inserted.

Comment: not live anywhere at mo sorry. You guys spotted anything obvious? I been studying for hours!

Comment: Something else, your could get rid of using $time =time(); and use NOW() in your INSERT statement.

Comment: Maybe for some reason the mouseout event is called twice, check it with Firebug or some other development tool how often the ajax request is send to the server. You could use console.info('text') to show at the js console each ajax post to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should get rid of the post rendering in the update.php.

**EDIT:** I'm a bit lost in your code. As I see you're completely rendering the post again and replace the original one.

You should only update the comments, actually you don't have to get any html response from the ajax request. A success/fail flag would be enough. You can put the new comment from the editable area to the bottom (or top) of the comment list on success.

Update php:

```
include("connectdb.php");
include_once("secure.php");

//still repeating posts when mutiple comments added?
$commentpostid = protect($_POST['postid']);
$commentuserid = protect($_POST['commentuserid']);
$comment = protect($_POST['comment']);
$time =time();

$comment = strip_tags($comment);

$query = "INSERT INTO comments
            (comment_uid, comment_pid, comment, comment_time)
          VALUES
            ($commentuserid ,$commentpostid, '$comment', $time)";

if(mysql_query($sql_insert_comments))
{
    echo "OK";
}
else
{
    echo "FAIL";
}
```

You'll get "OK" or "FAIL" as response data. So you can make the right move in JS:

```
$(".editable").live('click', function(){
    $(this).empty();
    $(this).mouseout(function() {
        var comment = $(this).html();
        var postid = $(this).attr("pid");
        var commentuserid = $("#loggedin").attr("uid");

        if(comment == ""){
            return false;
        }else{
            var datastring = 'comment=' + comment + '&postid=' + postid + '&commentuserid=' + commentuserid;
            //save with ajax clear box and then load back in
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "uploadcomment.php",
                data: datastring,
                success: function(data){
                            if(data == "OK") {
                                //put comment into the comment list
                            } else {
                                alert('error');
                            }
                         }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

You should slightly modify your comment list for this. You should put the comments into a container div, sou you'll be able to append the new commit to the list with jQuery like

`$("#post_1 div.comment_container").append($("<div/>").text('comment text'))`

Also needed to store the posts in signed wrappers to be able to figure out which post's comment list should be updated. So the structure of the page should look like this:

```
<div class="post_list">
    <div class="post" id="post_1">
        <!-- post body -->
        <div class="comment_container">
            <!-- comments -->
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="post" id="post_2">
        <!-- post body -->
        <div class="comment_container">
            <!-- comments -->
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="post" id="post_3">
        <!-- post body -->
        <div class="comment_container">
            <!-- comments -->
        </div>
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

**EDIT:** And the real solution would be to remove the "left join comments" from the query where you're getting the post. The join multiplies the rows.

For instance:
You've got A, B post, with comments A <= a,b and B <= c,d,e.
The result of the query would be 5 lines if I'm correct.

Comment: if a remove post rendering I just have comments and they still duplicate.

Comment: @sherwoodbear check on my last edit, hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: hi Thanks for this, could you explain the first solution a bit more. I tried losing the left join comments but it is throwing errors. So I am trying the update comment solution but its not working could expand on that idea? sorry I am new to this.

Comment: What's the error message?The query shoud be: "SELECT 
    post.post, 
    post.posttime, 
    post.pid_imageurl, 
    post.likes, 
    user.name, 
    user.uid_imageurl, 
    post.pid
FROM post
INNER JOIN user ON post.uid=user.uid
ORDER BY pid DESC"

Comment: this looks like the solution, being new I can visualise what needs to be done but not got the code in my head yet to do it! cheers Damien.

Comment: Keep on trying and never give up! Good luck and have fun

Comment: this has been solved removal of left JOIN (as stated yesterday) ...my coding eyes where so blind yesterday!

Answer (score 0):

You should run separate queries to extract the postings and the comments.

As it is each time you add a comment your `SELECT` will return a whole new row containing both the original post and the current comment.

Separating the queries will not only fix this, it'll make the query to get the comments and their count much simpler, too.

Do:

```
SELECT     post.post, post.posttime, post.pid_imageurl, post.likes,
           user.name, user.uid_imageurl, post.pid
FROM       post
INNER JOIN user  ON post.uid = user.uid
ORDER BY   pid DESC
```

and fetch all of those records into an array, then followed by

```
SELECT     comments.comment, comments.comment_time,
           user.name, user.uid_imageurl
FROM       comments
INNER JOIN user ON  comments.comment_uid = user.uid
WHERE      comment_pid = ?
ORDER BY   cid DESC
```

to get the comment data (and indirectly their count)